# ErrorException - Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ServiceProvider.php line 84 in Lumen

Tags: laravel-5, lumen

I am new to **Lumen** so I just downloaded and installed a fresh lumen setup but unfortunately as soon as I hit postman it sends me above error. I have read many posts all says to use `isset()` i did so but still error persists therefore i request to help me.
`Composer update` also does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue between your version of PHP  and Lumen 5.*

I found something here https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume/issues/82

This worked for me

```
// in bootstrap/app.php
$app->configure('view');
```